# Advanced Python and Program Structure

Tags: python, devops, software-design

I've been casually programming in Python for a number of years now, and my devops role is increasingly shifting more towards the dev side of things.

My issue is that my programs still look a bit amateurish when compared to some of the projects I see online, and I'm struggling to find resources to learn from to bridge the gap between my current skill set and that of a more seasoned programmer.
In particular, I find that when I look at examples of advanced Python projects online, I can't follow the structure of the program, and how all the elements fit together.

If I search for "Advanced Python" courses or resources, I tend to only find examples of more advanced Python elements and syntax, but not how to build a well-structured program incorporating those elements. So my programs still look like a collection of scripts, just with more advanced syntax.

My question is therefore, are there any gold-standard or well-known resources that programmers are learning from to turn their programs into something more professional?

Comment: check out https://www.arjancodes.com/ he also has a youtube page for intermediate/advanced python programming

Comment: Troll through github and look at several [cookiecutter templates](https://github.com/search?q=cookiecutter&type=Repositories) that have been built for Python. Also read through this: [Structuring Your Project](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/).